# Fetch googlesheet data using access token?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, fetch

I want to fetch googlesheet data. Through my code I am able to get the access token but now I don't know how can I fetch all the records in a googlesheet using that particular access token in javascript.
I have given the scope in manifest as spreadsheet.readonly.
I have my token in a particular variable and also googlesheeetId in another variable now what headers and what url do I need to paas so that I can get the googlesheet data.
Please help with some reference or links or sample code so that I can get a glimpse of what process do I need to follow to do this.

**Here is the code**

```
var gSheetId;

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function (token) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;
  }
  console.log(token);

  //getting googlesheetId from user
  gSheetId = prompt("Please provide your googlesheet Id");
  if (!gSheetId) {
    alert("Operation Cannot be Performed! Please refresh");
  } 
  else {
    //read googlesheetdata
    var headers = {
      'Authorization':'Bearer '+token
    }
    //here I need to read the googlesheet data using the token
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
  }
});
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you tried going through [Google Sheet´s API reference for Javascript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md)? There you can find a set up with some documentation on how to acess google sheets with a JavaScript client. Also,just to make sure, are you intending to use JavaScript or Apps Script?

Comment: Only javascript! But As I already said that I have the access token get by using chrome.identity.getAuthtoken() and now I just want to make a get call to my googlesheet to read the data using the access token.

Comment: Also, [HERE](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) is a more insightful and easier to follow resource to use Google Sheets with the browser (i.e HTML and JavaScript). Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your code so that it is easier for me to follow this issue?

Comment: OK! let me edit my question!

Comment: Edited it! Now you can check.

Comment: ok great, will take a look to see what can I find out. Thanks.

Comment: What type or format of data are you looking to get?

Comment: It can be of JSON

Comment: @StayAtOrbit What application is this for? A browser one or are you trying to make a Chrome extension? I managed to run an application following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js), if what you are looking for is a simple JavaScript application I can show you how to get data from a sheet posting an answer to this question.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Yes I am making an extension when the user clicks on the extension it will ask for signin(if not signedIn in chrome) ans then ask for gSheetId in prompt after providing the id I must be able to read the googlesheet associated to that particularId.

Comment: Ok perfect, I will take a look at how to achieve this with chrome extensions then

Comment: @StayAtOrbit so after taking a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.) and [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/cors.md#making-authenticated-requests) I believe you just need to send the token on a request header, take a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.). Let me know if that help in any way.

Comment: Are you making an authorization request with the token passed in the headers?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf No! Using getAuthToken() provides me the access token which can be generated after full authorization. So I just need to read the googlesheet using access token. As I have also checked my generated token in OAuth 2.0 Playground by replacing the access token which the generated one and It perfectly works fine.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf By passing the authorization with token in headers lets my get request to validate that the incoming requests is valid and can access the gSheet. You will get a glimpse what I need after using OAuth 2.0 Playground. Just you need to select scope and authorize it then you will get access token and after that just select the get values under list possible operations and there you will go!

Comment: Issue Solved...!

Comment: code in else section `//read googlesheetdata
    var obj = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Host': 'sheets.googleapis.com',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
      }
    }
    fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<sheetID>/values/<range>', obj)
      .then(function (res) {
        return console.log(res.json());
      })
      .then(function (resJson) {
        return console.log(resJson);
      })`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Brought to you by @StayAtOrbit , owner of the oiginal question. *(this is a community wiki answer)*

Useful resources for this issue:

- [Google sheets API documentation for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md)
- [Sending access token to an API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.)
- [Making authentificated requests with a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.)

```js
var gSheetId;

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function (token) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;
  }
  console.log(token);

  //getting googlesheetId from user
  gSheetId = prompt("Please provide your googlesheet Id");
  if (!gSheetId) {
    alert("Operation Cannot be Performed! Please refresh");
  } 
  else { //read googlesheetdata
    var obj = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Host': 'sheets.googleapis.com',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token 
      }
    }
 fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<sheetID>/values/<range>', obj)
.then(function (res) {
return console.log(res.json());
}).then(function (resJson) {
return console.log(resJson);
})
    //here I need to read the googlesheet data using the token
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
  }
});
```